# Ruby equivalent of curl with -H (header) switch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I want to do what this curl request does, but in Ruby:

```
curl https://api.wheniwork.com/2/shifts/?location_id=1&start=2014-03-05 \
-H "W-Token: ilovemyboss"
```

The part that I am struggling with is: How can I add the `w-Token` at the end of a regular HTTPS request?

Comment: Do you mean like this `curl https://api.wheniwork.com/2/shifts/?location_id=1&start=2014-03-05&W-Token=ilovemyboss` ?

Comment: No @Abhi I am referring to this link http://dev.wheniwork.com/?shell#login and they have stated that they want curl https://api.wheniwork.com/2/login \
  --data '{"username":"user@example.com","password":"*******"}' \
  -H "W-Key: iworksoharditsnotfunny"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example how this can be accomplished with a standard library net/http:

```
require 'net/http'
url = '...'
uri = URI(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
request['authorization'] = %{Token token="#{password}", userID="#{user_id}"}
res = http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 2):

-H represents HTTP header. You can pass by using [HTTPClient](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient)

Install the httpclient gem

```
gem install httpclient
```

Then fetch the URL using code sample given below

```
require 'httpclient'

uri = "https://api.wheniwork.com/2/shifts/"
query = "location_id=1&start=2014-03-05"
clnt = HTTPClient.new
extheader = { 'W-Token' => 'ilovemyboss' }
clnt.get_content(uri, query, extheader)
```